# Spring Security with OAuth2 without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot 2.7 but no AuthenticationEventPublisher

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, audit-logging

My old security config code based on Spring Boot 2.6 worked fine:

```java
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                . . . 
            .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt();
    }
}
```

I am now upgrading the usage of deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class in favour of a method with `@Bean` to return `SecurityFilterChain` [as recommended](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) and my applications have no valid `AuthenticationEventPublisher` anymore:

```java
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                . . . 
            .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The reason for my problem is: the object `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` uses `ProviderManager` as `AuthenticationManager` (even before using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`).
But as default `ProviderManager` declares its `AuthenticationEventPublisher` this way:

```java
public class ProviderManager implements AuthenticationManager, . . . {

    . . .

    private AuthenticationEventPublisher eventPublisher = new NullEventPublisher();
```

**There it is the problem: NullEventPublisher is a null implementation which doesn't publish events.**

And before when using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` - the eventPublisher object of `ProviderManager` was assigned with `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher` object

After some tests I was able to "fix the problem" with the following code:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({AuthenticationEventPublisher.class, JwtAuthenticationProvider.class})
public class SpringConfiguration { //global configuration for several others
    @Bean
    public ProviderManager providerManagerAvecDefaultAuthenticationPublisher(@Lazy JwtDecoder jwtDecoder, AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationPublisher) {
        JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder);
        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider));
        providerManager.setAuthenticationEventPublisher(authenticationPublisher);
        return providerManager;
    }
}
```

And also adjusting my security configuration:

```java
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig {

    @Autowired ProviderManager manager; //1

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                . . . 
            .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt()
                    .authenticationManager(manager); //2
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But I have two concerns:

1. The purpose of my module/application is to be used by other applications of my company in order to publish specific logs. And this solution will force dozens of applications to add the lines with comments 1 and 2
2. I am not aware of the risks of "forcing" a pre-built `ProviderManager` for those applications

So finally my question here is: Is there a way to bypass `eventPublisher = new NullEventPublisher()` from `ProviderManager` without forcing to configure `oauth2ResourceServer().authenticationManager(manager)` in all applications configuring its `SecurityFilterChain`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your assumption about the default `AuthenticationEventPublisher` is correct.
In fact, the default one (`DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher`) is provided via the Spring Security autoconfiguration: `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration#authenticationEventPublisher()`.
Then it's picked up by `AuthenticationConfiguration` which creates an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` which upon request creates the mentioned `ProviderManager` with the populated event publisher.

Comment: Using Spring Security autoconfiguration the problem remains.

My AuthenticationManagerBuilder object is of type DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder with eventPublisher null.
Its parentAuthenticationManager is the good ProviderManager created by SecurityAutoConfiguration as you said.

Essential class for me is BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter but its authenticationManager = bad ProviderManager with NullEventPublisher.

Comment: Why BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter never used my "good" ProviderManager? It seems the origin of the problem is at the class OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer # configure(H http) that always configure the bad ProviderManager, except if specified